# Laravel Passport Backpack Api returns 404

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-backpack

Currently working on creating an API for my Laravel Backpack application. I have followed the instructions [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport) on getting this setup, but I am getting a Backpack Error 404 when I try to GET /user

How do I fix this?

routes/api.php

```
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

No stacktrace that I'm aware of. Postman just gives me the 404 page. Nothing in logs.

If I take out the `->middleware('auth:api');` line, then it works with no authentication, but I want to use an API token to authenticate with.

Comment: well, any stacktrace left? logs? and does `GET /user` properly defined in the routes..?

Comment: Just noticed something funny, the 404 for /user and the 404 for /api/user looks different.

Answer (score 0):

thats an api route.. see the route service provider. there should be a prefix set. so the url would be

```
/api/user
```

not

```
/user
```

Comment: I am hitting /api/user and getting the 404